# Reflection IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, reflection

I need to get private fields from one class and set them to another class.

This code works perfectly well for test Integer fields (100500 value gets written):

```
//get objects, class firs...

for(int i =0; i<fields1.length; i++) {
    Field field1 = fields1 [i];
    Field field = fields [i];
    field.setAccessible(true);
    field.set(app,  new Integer(100500));       
}
```

Nontheless, when I switch to undefined type (the fields are of DIFFERENT types: Dates, Integers, Strings...

Eg class one has  Date and class two has Date, I need to copy one value from another, but next field is going to be String in both classes)

```
for(int i =0; i<fields1.length; i++) {
    Field field1 = fields1 [i];
    Field field = fields [i];
    field.setAccessible(true);
    field.set(app,  field1);        
}
```

I receive an IllegalArgumentException, e.g. I am not really able to get the values from one class and set it into another.

Please, dear community, give me a hint - what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You seem to be assuming the fields will be returned in the same order. That sounds like a bad idea to me. If one class has a single date field and the other has two date fields, what do you actually want to do? Populate both fields? Just the first one? Match by name?

Comment: both classes have the same amount of the same fields appearing in the same order, i want to copy one values to another

Comment: In the same order in the source file? Does the documentation guarantee that that's the order they'll be returned?

Answer (score 2):

to me, it looks like you hand over the field-reference instead of the field-value:

```
for(int i =0; i<fields1.length; i++) {
        Field field1 = fields1 [i];
        Field field = fields [i];
        field.setAccessible(true);
        field.set(app,  field1.get(app1)); //or whatever object field1 is from        
        }
```

though i would not do it that way because order is a fragile thing...
you could use [beanutils](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/v1.8.3/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtils.html#copyProperties%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29) to copy your beans, if it is, what you want to achieve

Answer (score 2):

This should suit your needs:

```java
public static <T> void copyDeclaredFields(T from, T to) throws Exception {
    Class<?> clazz = from.getClass();
    if (!clazz.equals(to.getClass())) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    for (Field field : clazz.getDeclaredFields()) {
        Object value = field.get(from);
        field.set(to, value);
    }
}
```

To call:

```java
Item item1 = new Item();
// item1.set...
Item item2 = new Item();
copyDeclaredFields(item1, item2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your error seems to be related to the fact that you are trying to set *Field1* as parameter of Field, instead of the *value* of Field1.

```
field.set(app,  field1);
```

should instead be

```
field.set(app,  field1.get(app1));
```

Take a look at [a small working example](https://ideone.com/IUS35Z);

If you change

```
fieldDest.set(destination, fieldSrc.get(source));
```

to

```
fieldDest.set(destination, fieldSrc);
```

you will get the same error of this question.

Hope that helps.

Code of the example:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.lang.reflect.*;

class Main
{

        public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
        {
            Source source = new Source();
        Destination destination = new Destination();


        Class sourceClassObject = source.getClass();
        Class destClassObject = destination.getClass();
        Field[] sourceFields = sourceClassObject.getDeclaredFields();
        Field[] destFields = destClassObject.getDeclaredFields();

        for (Field fieldSrc : sourceFields) {
            int mod = fieldSrc.getModifiers();  // get modifiers
            System.out.print("Source Field: " + Modifier.toString(mod) + " "
              + fieldSrc.getType() + " " + fieldSrc.getName());
            fieldSrc.setAccessible(true);
            System.out.println(" [" + fieldSrc.get(source) + "]");
            for (Field fieldDest : destFields){
                if (fieldDest.getType().equals(fieldSrc.getType()) && 
                    fieldDest.getName().equals(fieldSrc.getName())){
                    fieldDest.setAccessible(true);
                    fieldDest.set(destination, fieldSrc.get(source));
                }                
            }
        }

        destination.printValues();
    }

    static class Source{        

        public Source(){
            strField = "This is a String";
            intField = 42;
            dateField = new Date();
        }

        private String  strField;
        private Integer intField;
        private Date    dateField;
    }

    static class Destination{        
        private String  strField;
        private Integer intField;
        private Date    dateField;

        public void printValues(){
            System.out.println("Destination Field values: ");
            System.out.println("strField: " + strField);
            System.out.println("intField: " + intField);
            System.out.println("dateField: " + dateField);
        }
    }    
}
```